# How do I set X-UA-Compatible header to IE=EmulateIE7 for IE 8 browsers using Apache 2.0?

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am able to set this header

```
X-UA-Compatible "IE=EmulateIE7"
```

using the following directive in my Apache 2.0 httpd.conf file:

```
<Location /mypath>
   Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=EmulateIE7"
</Location>
```

How can I configure Apache to only set this header for IE 8 browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best I could come up with so far.  It *seems* to work.  If anyone has a better way, please let me know.

```
BrowserMatch "^.*MSIE 8.*$" emulate_ie7

<Location /mypath>
   Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=EmulateIE7" env=emulate_ie7
</Location>
```

Comment: Yes .. it works. For case insensitive match better if we use BrowserMatchNoCase